# A Workflow Foundation 4 argument of a nested type

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

One of the arguments to my workflow (xaml) is a nested type declared in a static class. Unfortunately, the "Browse for .NET type" dialog box does not show me this type irrespective of what I search for

`full.namespace.containingstaticlass.typeIneed`

or

`full.namespace.containingstaticlass+typeIneed`

Since the dialog didn't work, I tried editing the xaml itself but couldn't figure out how to define the

`Type="InArgument(xmlnamespacetomyassembly:???)"`

Help!?

*Edit:* It seems the Workflow Designer does not work with nested types at all, because an expression to cast an object to a nested type gave me this error.

[image]

At this point, any workarounds will be most welcome!

Added a [simple sample](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18222766/WorkflowNestedTypesFail.zip) that shows the problem.

1. There is no way to add a parameter (in the designer) of type NestedType.EssentialStruct
2. Even if you add an expression to cast Object to NestedType.EssentialStruct in the properties window against any InArgument, the designer will complain.

Posting the relevant sections also:

The nested type that needs to be used in the CodeActivity

```
public static class NestedTypes
{
    public struct EssentialStruct
    {
    }
}
```

A simple activity that uses the nested type as an InArgument and result

```
public sealed class TestActivity : CodeActivity<NestedTypes.EssentialStruct>
{
    public InArgument<NestedTypes.EssentialStruct> Handle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override NestedTypes.EssentialStruct Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        return context.GetValue(this.Handle);
    }
}
```

I can't post the XAML that produces the error because the designer doesn't save it, errors out just before saving it.

Comment: Are you using the x:Type markup extension?

Comment: @Will - I tried, but ran into two issues. One, the x:Type extension does not support this syntax either. Second, somewhere else in the Xaml - nodes of this nested types were being created which also caused the designer to barf. I will edit my code with a small, concise sample when I get to work.

Comment: That's not really useful.  Adding the relevant section of the xaml in an [edit] is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use import on the workflow. It's a tab in the designer. It's next to variables and arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but the assembly this type lives in is already imported. I can see the enclosing (static) class just fine. Its the nested type I don't know how to declare an argument of.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the referenced assembly is built in x86 (or Any CPU). I had the same problem and it turned out that the referenced DLL was x64 which made it so the Visual Studio designer couldn't see it.